# Create button with multiple border

Tags: html, css

I need to create this kind of button for a website design :

[image]

The problem is that I really don't see how I can achieve this with CSS. I was thinking about border and box-shadow but I cannot find a proper way to do it.

Any help welcome!

Thanks

Comment: you can use multiple shadows on the box shadow property see https://alligator.io/css/box-shadow-examples/ for some inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something close to what you want would be:

```css
.extra-bordered {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 1px white, 0px 0px 0 3px black, 4px 4px 0 2px white, 4px 4px 0 3px black;
}
```

```html
<button class="extra-bordered">More About US</button>
```

Yes, this won't be good with background-image of **body**. You can also try the `border-image` property to achieve this if you have no provision to use image.

Answer (score 5):

yes you can use box shadow as shown in the code attached

as pointed out in comments , *this will not work well if transparent background is required*

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 7px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px green,
              6px 6px 0 0 white,
              6px 6px 0 2px blue,
              12px 12px 0 0 white,
              12px 12px 0 2px red;
}
```

```html
<div> more about us </div>
```

Comment: This won’t play nice with a background though